ckeditor5 add additional span-tags, ckeditor4 did not
In TYPO3 v11 everything was working fine with ckeditor4. Now in TYPO3 v12 there is ckeditor5 and we have big issues with the automatically adjusted html from this editor.
Let's assume we have the following html we enter in the code-view of ckeditor5:
<p>
    <span class="font-size-s">Text S <strong>Etiam</strong> orci. <i>Duis leo</i> Sed fringilla. <u>Sed consequat</u>, leo eget. <a class="internal-page" href="t3://page?uid=38" target="_blank">interner Link</a> END.</span>
</p>

after we switch back to html-view the code gets changed by ckeditor and if we switch back to code-view we see the following:
<p>
    <span class="font-size-s">Text <strong>strong</strong> text </span><i><span class="font-size-s">italic</span></i><span class="font-size-s"> text <u>underline</u> text </span><a class="internal-page" href="t3://page?uid=38" target="_blank"><span class="font-size-s">link</span></a><span class="font-size-s"> END</span>
</p>

The initial span-tag gets broken up in mutliple tags while keeping the strong-tag and u-tag in a span, but creating a new span inside the i-tag and the a-tag. Why is ckeditor5 doing this? In ckeditor4 this was possible and no issue. With the now broken up html we have big problems.
How do we configure ckeditor to not do this?
We tried a lot of things but nothing worked. We only could achieve a partial success while getting the i-tag running inside the span with this written plugin. Something similar failed for the a-tag:
Our additional ckeditor-config.js:
import { Core, UI } from "@typo3/ckeditor5-bundle.js";
export default class Dialoop extends Core.Plugin {
    static get pluginName() {
        return 'Dialoop';
    }

    init() {
        console.log('ckeditor dialoop init');
        const editor = this.editor;
        const model = editor.model;
        const schema = model.schema;

        // Register and extend the 'i' element
        schema.register('i', {
            allowWhere: '$text',
            allowContentOf: '$text',
            isInline: true,
            isObject: false
        });

        // Register and extend the 'a' element
        schema.register('a', {
            allowWhere: '$text',
            allowContentOf: '$text',
            isInline: true,
            isObject: false,
            allowAttributes: ['href', 'target', 'class'] // Extend attributes as needed
        });

        // Allow spanClass attribute on $text
        schema.extend('$text', {
            allowAttributes: 'spanClass'
        });

        // Allow spanClass attribute on 'i'
        schema.extend('i', {
            allowAttributes: 'spanClass'
        });

        // Allow spanClass attribute on 'a'
        schema.extend('a', {
            allowAttributes: 'spanClass'
        });

        // Downcast converter for span with classes
        editor.conversion.for('downcast').attributeToElement({
            model: 'spanClass',
            view: (attributeValue, { writer }) => {
                return writer.createAttributeElement('span', {
                    class: attributeValue
                }, {
                    priority: 7
                });
            }
        });

        // Upcast converter for span with any classes
        editor.conversion.for('upcast').elementToAttribute({
            view: {
                name: 'span',
                attributes: {
                    class: true
                }
            },
            model: {
                key: 'spanClass',
                value: viewElement => viewElement.getAttribute('class')
            }
        });
    }
}

after running this plugin we got this html. The i-tag is now inside the outer span, but the a-tag is still wrong:
<p>
    <span class="font-size-s">Text <strong>strong</strong> text <i>italic</i> text <u>underline</u> text </span><a class="internal-page" href="t3://page?uid=38" target="_blank"><span class="font-size-s">link</span></a><span class="font-size-s"> END</span>
</p>

We included the custom ckeditor-config.js in our site-extension via /Configuration/JavaScriptModules.php:
<?php

return [
    'dependencies' => ['backend'],
    'tags' => [
        'backend.form',
    ],
    'imports' => [
        '@diasite/ckeditor-dialoop' => 'EXT:diasite/Resources/Public/JavaScript/ckeditor-config.js',
    ],
];

For reference the Custom.yaml file we use in TYPO3 to configure the ckeditor5:
# Load default processing options
imports:
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Processing.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Base.yaml" }
  - { resource: "EXT:rte_ckeditor/Configuration/RTE/Editor/Plugins.yaml" }

# Add configuration for the editor
# For complete documentation see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config
editor:
  config:
    importModules:
      - '@diasite/ckeditor-dialoop'

    contentsCss: "/system/Public/StyleSheets/rte.css?v=24"
    stylesSet:
      - { name: "Text XS (Quellenangabe)", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-size-xs"}}
      - { name: "Text S (≙ H4)", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-size-s"}}
      - { name: "Text M (≙ H3)", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-size-m"}}
      - { name: "Text L (≙ H2)", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-size-l"}}
      - { name: "Text XL (≙ H1)", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-size-xl"}}
      - { name: "Primärfarbe", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-color-1"}}
      - { name: "Sekundärfarbe", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-color-2"}}
      - { name: "schwarz", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-color-black"}}
      - { name: "weiß", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-color-white"}}
      - { name: "Highlight", element: "span", attributes: {class: "font-highlight"}}
      - { name: "Liste mit Häkchen", element: "ul", attributes: {class: "unordered-content-list-2"}}

    format_tags: "p;h1;h2;h3;h4"

    toolbarGroups:
      - { name: styles, groups: [ styles, format ] }
      - { name: basicstyles, groups: [ basicstyles ] }
      - { name: paragraph, groups: [ list, blocks, align ] }
      - { name: links, groups: [ links ] }
      - { name: clipboard, groups: [ clipboard, cleanup, undo ] }
      - { name: editing, groups: [ spellchecker ] }
      - { name: insert, groups: [ insert ] }
      - { name: tools, groups: [ table, specialchar ] }
      - { name: document, groups: [ mode ] }

    justifyClasses:
      - text-left
      - text-center
      - text-right
      - text-justify

    extraPlugins:
      - justify

    removePlugins:
      - image

    removeButtons:
      - Anchor
      - Strike
      - Image
      - indent
      - align
      - Acronym
      - About
      - JustifyLeft
      - JustifyCenter
      - JustifyRight
      - JustifyBlock
      - Blockquote


classesAnchor:

  internalLink:
    class: 'internal-page'
    type: 'page'

  internalLinkButton:
    class: 'link-button'
    type: 'page'

  externalLink:
    class: 'external-page'
    type: 'url'

  externalLinkButton:
    class: 'link-button'
    type: 'url'

  downloadLink:
    class: 'file-download'
    type: 'file'

  downloadButton:
    class: 'link-button'
    type: 'file'

  mailLink:
    class: 'mail-address'
    type: 'mail'

  mailButton:
    class: 'link-button'
    type: 'mail'

  faxLink:
    class: 'fax-link'
    type: 'telephone'

  telLink:
    class: 'tel-link'
    type: 'telephone'

buttons:
  link:
    page:
      properties:
        class:
          default: 'internal-page'
    url:
      properties:
        class:
          default: 'external-page'
        target:
          default: '_blank'
    mail:
      properties:
        class:
          default: 'mail-address'
    telephone:
      properties:
        class:
          default: 'tel-link'
    download:
      properties:
        class:
          default: 'file-download'
    properties:
      class:
        allowedClasses: 'internal-page,external-page,mail-address,file-download,link-button,tel-link,fax-link'

classes:
  external-page:
    name: 'Externer Link'
  mail-address:
    name: 'E-Mail Link'
  internal-page:
    name: 'Interner Link'
  file-download:
    name: 'Datei Download'
  tel-link:
    name: 'Telefon'
  fax-link:
    name: 'Fax'
  link-button:
    name: 'Linkbutton'

We could not find any reference how to address this issue on the official documentation or via ChatGPT or simular AI.
